# Can Flow recognize undeclared React props?

Tags: reactjs, types, flowtype

Flow makes sure that you pass in the required props to React Components, but it seems that it doesn't catch errors when you send in *extra* props. This allows for subtle errors I occasionally make, where I type an incorrect version of a prop. In the example below, I pass in the prop `isloggedin` rather than the actual prop `isLoggedIn`, but no error is thrown because I have a default for `isLoggedIn`. Is there any way to get Flow to recognize cases where you are passing in a prop that is not declared in the component?

Component code:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from "react";

type Props = {
    isLoggedIn: boolean
};

class Donkey extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> {this.props.isLoggedIn.toString()} </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Donkey;
```

Calling code:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Donkey from "./Donkey";

type Props = {

}

class Main extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Donkey isloggedin={true} />
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Flow output:

```
> flow
No errors!
```

Comment: What about `type Props = {| ... |}` ?

Comment: @Sulthan Brilliant! Is there any reason not to use these everywhere? (New to Flow and not sure about best practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce exact type matching using `{| ... |}` (see https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types).

Flow will then report any missing or additional properties.

Why we don't use that anywhere? Mostly because in many situations we don't care whether there are some additional properties. That can happen for objects coming from JSON API or even for your own components, when the component is just passing some properties down to its children (e.g. `className`).

Comment: It makes sense that you'd want to allow extra properties from a JSON API request. But in practice, it seems that it wouldn't matter whether you use an exact type or not, because Flow's checks happen at compile-time, and the compiler doesn't know what will be received from the API request. When the API request actually comes through, Flow type annotations have been stripped out. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: @rampatowl That really depends on which type of flow checking you are using. For example, I am using flow-runtime, which checks values at runtime.